# Hibernate ORM 5.4.13.Final or higher @Where clause is not taken into account

Tags: hibernate, orm, annotations, version, where-clause

I have updated the version of Hibernate ORM to the latest stable: 5.4.15.Final, since I saw that one important issue has been resolved (ref: > https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8091).
And today we have noticed something else: that **@Where clause is not taken into account**.
We have @OneToMany relation, here is the example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
@Where(clause = "is_active = true and age(now(), created_ts) <= '4 days'")
private List<StudentMarkData> newMarks;
```

The where clause is not being added to the query at all.

Also, I could not see any difference in the documentation for using @Where.

The latest version that it works is **5.4.12.Final.**

Asked the question in a Hibernate Forum:
https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-orm-5-4-13-final-or-higher-where-clause-is-not-taken-into-account/4165